What is a 'craft backer' on a roll of flashing?
What is a 'craft backer' on a roll of flashing? Is it an adhesive? Another layer of metal? And what does the 3-ounce unit refer to in this context? Is it analogous to gauge?

...  laminated copper flashing with a 3oz craft backer that [can be used] with pressure treated lumber


It may be easier to find if you use the correct spelling: Kraft paper. One of the German words for strong.

I can read and speak German but there's also "arts and crafts" in English, referring to making decorative objects from a variety of materials. But the question  involved the word "backer" too, and wondering what the purpose of the backer was.

Yup, I got it. Isherwood has your answer for its use as a backer. I'm just saying that Kraft paper is a specific, standardized thing: it's brown, it's heavy and it's strong. It's what they use to make paper sacks for groceries. (In Germany they asked me "Eine Tüte?" if I didn't bring my own.) Craft paper comes in rainbow colors, various thicknesses and it is not particularly strong.

In any case, I as quoting the actual product description.

"Craft" (or kraft) paper is a heavy-weight material used on building products, often insulation, as a barrier for various purposes. The name refers to a wood pulping process used in its manufacture. In this case, it would serve to isolate the metal from a chemically harsh lumber treatment. For insulation it can act as a containment layer and prevents moisture migration.
"3 oz." refers to the specific paper weight (per unit of area--probably a yard). It gives an indication of relative thickness. It is a gauge of sorts.

Most pressure-treated lumber these days is treated with copper, so there shouldn't be any issue of galvanic corrosion unless the flashing  isn't really copper or is merely microscopically thin copper plating.  That's what had me wondering about the purpose of this backer.

CCA-treated lumber is still used in non-residential construction. Your point is valid here, though.
